# Bandwidth usage maxed out

Tags: windows-server-2008, bandwidth

some people working with me ask me to look around for answers about a bandwidth problem they've been having. The problem is simple, when one user download something all connection (like RDP and terminal services for exemple) drop dead. I'm using windows server 2008 and i've been looking around my 3COM switch 3CREVF100-73 for some sort of bandwidth control. On this switch i have one port that is use for a dmz and a port for an other switch (24 port) that is use for my private network.

Thanx in advance for any ideas you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [product page](http://www.3com.com/products/en_US/detail.jsp?tab=features&sku=3CREVF100-73&pathtype=purchase) for that switch does mention that it has this feature:

> Traffic shaping prioritizes traffic on
>   user-definable ports to guarantee
>   bandwidth

View chapter 12 of the [manual](http://support.3com.com/documents/firewall/3CREVF100-73/10016886_Rev_AA.pdf) for details about how to set this up.  You will probably need to create a couple rules to priorities important types of traffic like RDP.

But realistically if a single download kills your connection you almost certainly need to work on getting more bandwidth.  Traffic shaping can help a little, but if you link is saturated, it will won't really do anything other then slightly change what is using up all your bandwidth.

Comment: After reading this you gave me an idea to check on the cables in the walls, and it turn ou they are CAT 5 links. Since the company is growing fast no doubt this finaly play a major role in the bandwidth. Thank you!